# How to disable a category in the popup grid of a longlistselector for windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, longlistselector

I am attempting to write an applicaiton for WF 7.5 that includes an alphabetical list of recipes. I am using a LongListSelector to display this list as a jump list. Currently, the user can tap the category heading in the list and a grid appears with all of the letters of the alphabet (just like in the music app). Unfortunately, right now the user can select a greyed-out letter from the list and the LLS will put them in the adjacent category. What I would like to happen is for the user to remain in the grid view until they select a category with items in it, or they hit back. I have a variable that tells me if the category has items in it, but im not sure how to use it to disable specific categories in the grid view. I would appreciate any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just bind your variable to *IsHitTestVisible* property of the main element in your *GroupItemTemplate*. Just like that:

```
<LongListSelector.GroupHeaderTemplate>
    <Border IsHitTestVisible="{Binding CategoryHasItems}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CategoryTitle}"/>
    </Border>
</LongListSelector.GroupHeaderTemplate>
```